# Programmatically add a new file to TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to add a new file to TFS source control using C#.

Can anybody help me on the same?

Thanks,
Naresh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of [using the TFS API to checkin code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer.aspx).

Comment: Updated link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/